# How to figure out if row is equal to a specific input

Tags: php, database

I am trying to figure out how to get a specific input from a database and fetching it. If its not equal to 1 do function.

Example code:

```
$admincheck = "SELECT admin FROM users";

if($admincheck == 0){

echo "<p style='font-size:40px;text-align:center;'><strong>Du har ikke tilgang til å se dette innholdet.</p>";
```

In my user database i have Username, Password, Admin.
Admin is default 0. If the number is 1 i want to grant access to that specific website.

Comment: Learn the basics on how PHP and DB (guess here is mysql) is fetching data: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp Your "example code" and description is wrong on too many levels to give any type of answer....

Comment: After logging in, write down the user ID in the cookie or session, and then check.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect to the database and then run your query.  You will get a resultset back and you get the value you want from the resultset.  Then you can do whatever you need to do with the result.

Try something like the following (most of this was pulled from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "databasename");
$username = "whatever username you are checking";

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("select admin from users where username='$username'")) {
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
        $is_admin = $obj->admin;
        if ($is_admin === 0){
            echo "whatever html you want to echo";
        }
    }
    

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

You will need to make sure that your database prevents more than one person from having the same username, I recommend adding a unique index on username.  Usually people have an additional column called "id" that auto_increments so that it will always be a unique number and that's a lot easier to work with.

I recommend abstracting this logic into a separate file that will be responsible for verifying that the user is authenticated.

Comment: Thank you, will try this out. I have everything with the database etc set up. I just didnt show everything! :)

Answer (score 0):

this query is not for one column

```
$admincheck = "SELECT admin FROM users";
```

you should add a `where` condition and after that, you can check `if($admincheck == 0)`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT admin FROM users where id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row->admin_check == 1){
         /////this is your code to check admin...
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```